# Modifying href using jQuery generating inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

When leveraging jQuery to modify the href for a given link - using 'prop' or 'attr' - the call succeeds.  I can see the link change in developer tools, if I right click on the link and select "Open link in new tab" it works flawlessly.

**BUT**

If I attempt to simply click on the link, in the same tab, it, for whatever reason, keeps sending me to the old (non-modified) link as if it's cached on the browser or something.  This occurs in Firefox and Chrome.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker of your code?

Comment: Yeah, because this fiddle works okay in latest Chrome with jQuery 2.1.3: http://jsfiddle.net/npaxd4jt/

Comment: `$(".checkoutButton").prop("href", "http://newlink.com");`